# Object that stores String data

Tags: arrays, swift2

Sorry I'm new to Swift, and I need to create an Array of `String` data. I know about 2-D Arrays, but I would prefer `Objects` to store `String`.

```
stringObject[0] = ("MATISSE", "JASON SHAPIRO", "9:00AM", "EXPLORE THE TOPICS AND TOOLS RELATED TO TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT.", "TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT")

stringObject[1] = ("ROTHKO", "JIM WHITE", "9:00AM", "DISCUSS THE LATEST SET OF TOOLS USED TO HELP EASE SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT.", "JAVA TOOLS")
```

How do I initialized the `stringObject`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Object`s storing `String`s. Arrays are a subclass of Object, as is everything. What you are trying to achieve is a 2D array in Swift, yes?

Comment: Looks like you want an array of objects, not an array of arrays (you will cause problems for yourself, down the road).

Comment: Yes I want an array of objects, and not array of an array. Because I have data of about 4000 records, and I'm afraid the indexing of the Array may cause searching problems.

Would you guys recommend that I should go with array of arrays?

Comment: stringObject[0] = AnyObject()